# How to start a windows service of a remote machine from another service which is on a local machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I want to start a Windows service of a remote machine from a windows service of my local machine.

Comment: Are these two machines able to reach one another?

Comment: Yes, they are in reach. the only thing is i need to pass the username and password from my local service.